# limit of frac function

Tags: limits, fractions

I'm trying to find $$\lim _{x\to 0} ((e^x-1)\cdot \operatorname{frac}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right))$$
I thought maybe use squeeze theorem but then I have $$(e^x-1)\cdot \left(\:\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-1\right)\le (e^x-1)\cdot \operatorname{frac}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\le (e^x-1)\cdot \:\frac{1}{x}$$

where $\operatorname{frac}(x)=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$.

p.s - I can't use L'Hopipal rule.

Comment: What is frac(x). is it integer parts. if so the limit is zero.

Comment: it is $$x - ⌊x⌋$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fractional part is always between $0$ and $1$, and $e^x-1\to0$ as $x\to 0$, so you have something between $0\cdot(e^x-1)$ and $1\cdot(e^x-1)$, and those both approach $0$.

Comment: I just realized that I wrote the wrong thing...

Comment: I just realized that I wrote the wrong thing...
It shouls be $$\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

Comment: @kurt you really need to specify if that is equal to $frac(x)$ or $frac(\frac{1}{x})$

Comment: @hugh its  $$frac(1/x)$$. I modified the question.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

we have that

$$\forall X\in \Bbb R\;\; 0\leq X-\lfloor X\rfloor \leq 1$$

$$\implies \forall x\neq 0\;\; |f(x)|\leq |e^x-1|.$$

the limit when $x\to 0$ is zero.